# Convert a string/text into splunk friendly format

Tags: java, splunk

I need to log some details while running my code. The splunk doesn't index values for keys with spaces, quotes etc. Is there any standard procedure where I can convert any string/text to splunk friendly format.

Sample strings :

```
key=string1
key=hello word
key="Hi, How are you", she exclaimed.
key="Wow what a pic!!!!"
key=this word means 'hua' in hindi.
key=%$^##@@####3
```

etc

Comment: It might be better to change your indexer configuration so it can index those strings.

Comment: i need to convert my string to splunk format.... i do not have access to splunk servers. They have a common indexing for all logs so cannot change it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Splunk Logging best practice.](http://dev.splunk.com/view/logging-best-practices/SP-CAAADP6)

> If your values contain spaces, wrap them in quotes (for example, username="bob smith").

Since your key follow the standard and only values have special requirement, the above approach of wrapping them in quotes should work for you.

You need to escape your string, when it has special symbols , like " in your case

Escape the string something like this:

```
"\"Hi, How are you\", she exclaimed."
```

Details about escaping can be found [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/characters.html)

You may want to explore *[StringEscapeUtils.ESCAPE_JAVA](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.1/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringEscapeUtils.html#ESCAPE_JAVA)* from Apache Commons, if you do not want to write your own utility for escaping

Comment: if a string already have a quote , then what. For example : "Hi, How are you", she said.

Comment: i am talking about splunk format : If you do something like above, the splunk would show key value as : ("\") instead of ("Hi, How are you", she exclaimed.)

Comment: For splunk, I think you may have to use *custom field extraction*, but you have no control as you said,  So I dont have a solution, I am not an expert is splunk, Best of luck! http://answers.splunk.com/answers/66712/lookup-escaping-quotation-character-in-field-value.html
http://answers.splunk.com/answers/3231/escaping-characters-in-an-event.html

Answer (score 2):

Well, you can do one of this :

1. manually create field extractions to accommodate these logs
2. wrap them in quote and escape the quote (`\"`). Then, set the `KV_MODE` in splunk `props.conf` to `auto_escaped`. for a further information, you can check this [link](http://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/6.0/admin/Propsconf). and this is what the `auto_escaped` value will do (taken from the documentation)

   > extracts fields/value pairs separated by equal signs and honors \" and \ 
   >         as escaped sequences within quoted values, e.g field="value with \"nested\" quotes"